# Xcode Firebase getting error Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "(null)" when uploading user info

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I'm making a simple Firebase app on xcode which involves a user uploading their username, password, email, and a profile image. I had everything working fine, but when I added my code to upload their profile image, nothing has worked since. This is the error I'm getting when I hit register:

> 2022-07-10 22:12:58.587723-0700 The Slap[13158:510029]
> GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 73, bytes =
> 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, error
> Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "(null)"
> UserInfo={data={length = 73, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a
> 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, data_content_type=application/json;
> charset=UTF-8}

Here's my code:

```
@objc func handleRegister() {
    guard let profileImage = profileImage else {
        self.errorLabel.text = "Please select a profile image"
        return
    }
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else {return}
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else {return}
    guard let fullName = nameTextField.text else {return}
    guard let userName = usernameTextField.text else {return}
    
    guard let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
    
    let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = STORAGE_PROFILE_IMAGES.child(filename)
    
    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { meta, error in
        storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                guard let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        self.errorLabel.text =  "\(error.localizedDescription)"
                        return
                    }
                    
                guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }
                    
                let values = ["email": email,
                              "password": password,
                              "fullName": fullName,
                              "username": userName,
                              "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
                    
                    print("DEGUG: Successfully registered user")
                    
                    REF_USERS.child(uid).updateChildValues(values) { error, ref in
                        print("DEBUG: Successfully updated user information")
                    }
                }
        }
        }
    }
```

On another Swift file I have the following constants:

```
import Firebase

let DB_REF = Database.database().reference()

//User Reference
let REF_USERS = DB_REF.child("users")

//Images
let STORAGE_REF = Storage.storage().reference()
let STORAGE_PROFILE_IMAGES = STORAGE_REF.child("profile_images")
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I put the google appspot url here:

1. `let STORAGE_REF = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "(Inser your url here")`
2. Inside my Firebase, under Storage > Rules, I changed the present rules to

```
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {

  match /b/{bucket}/o {

    match /{allPaths=**} {

      allow read, write }}}
```